# How do I group messages in JBoss ESB?

Tags: jboss-esb

I have JSON messages incoming to JMS queue on JBoss server.
I want to group them using some criteria, e.g. parse and use attribute "group" to group by.
I need to accumulate messages for X minutes, then create a new message representing each group and call a service to process each group-message.

I can't find a way to read messages from JMS queue and produce less ESB messages in transactional way. I don't want to loose messages during restart.

Answer (score 0):

If you stumbled upon this like I did. I suggest you use a message Aggregator for this. Please have a look at the following link for more details on how to. https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_SOA_Platform/4.2/html-single/SOA_ESB_Message_Action_Guide/index.html#section-Aggregator